# Find the number of the ideals in this ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**Question)**
Let the integer set, $Z$

The ring, $R = Z/ \langle 300 \rangle$

For ideal $I$ of $R$ $s.t.$ $I = \langle a \rangle / \langle 300 \rangle$

Then How many number of the $I$ which is commutative ring with unity?

---

**My trail)**

Since $R$ has a element that $1+ \langle 300 \rangle$, $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Hence $I$  is a commutative.

(1) Plus, If the ideal $I $ have a unity $s.t. I \subset R$, then $R=I$

(2) By third isomorphic theorem, $R/I \simeq (Z/<300>) / (<a> / 300) \simeq Z/<a>$

By (1) and (2), All we have to do is just find the $a \vert 300$  $s.t.$ $\vert Z/<a> 
\vert = 1$

Hence $a = \pm 1$. (The number of the the $I$ is $1$).

---

But the answer sheet said there are $a = 1,3,4,12,25,72,100,300$.
Therefore there are $8$ ideals.

There aren't any solution in my text book. They give me only answer. :(

*I don't know **why I'm not correct** and why should be $a = 1,3,4,12,25,75,100,300$?*

Any help would be thanksful.

Comment: How did you conclude $(1)$?

Comment: @AnuragA What if the unify is not $1 + \langle 1 \rangle $ in $I$?

Comment: @xbh,  $\vert Z/<a> \vert = 1$ . Hence, $a$ generates the $Z$(i.e. <a> = Z). Therefore $a = 1 or -1$

Comment: You get the requirement incorrect. See the answer below.

Comment: @xbh Thanks for your comment, it helped me understand what OP was (possibly) looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I believe you are looking for those ideals $I$ of $R=\Bbb{Z}/300\Bbb{Z}$ such that **$R/I$ is a commutative ring with identity**. If not, then I am not sure what you are asking and this whole answer is meaningless.*

By the correspondence theorem (basically using the projection map $\pi:\Bbb{Z} \longrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/300\Bbb{Z}$) the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}/300\Bbb{Z}$ are in bijective correspondence to ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ that contain $300\Bbb{Z}$. The ideals that contain $300\Bbb{Z}$ are of the form $d\Bbb{Z}$, where $d \mid 300$.

Moreover by the third isomorphism theorem
$$R/I=\left(\Bbb{Z}/300\Bbb{Z}\right)/\left(d\Bbb{Z}/300\Bbb{Z}\right) \cong \Bbb{Z}/d\Bbb{Z}.$$
Now (if) we want $R/I$ to be commutative ring with identity, we want an (identity) element $d\alpha \in [d]_{300}$ such that 
$$d(d\alpha) \equiv d \pmod{300} \implies d\alpha \equiv 1 \pmod{\frac{300}{d}}.$$
This means we want those $d$ such that

> $$\gcd\left(d, \frac{300}{d}\right)=1.$$

Now you can get the values of $d$ that are you looking for. Essentially your $d=2^{a} \,3^{b} \,5^{c}$, and based on the condition derived above, the choices for $a,b,c$ are $a=0,2, \,\, b=0,1, \,\, c=0,2$, a totality of $8$ possibilities.

**NOTE:** one of the values in your answer is a typo. Instead of $72$ it should be $75$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I almost got the congruence relation that derives the problem.

Comment: @Anurag A, I edited my typo. I've checked my book and the book said unity not identity. But the answer was that you suggested. It look like the author(Not English USER) confused concept between identity and unity. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang In present context, "identity" and "unity" are used to describe the same object.

Comment: Really? Aren't there different things? I can't understand Why they are same. Could you please more explain why does they are same object?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang According to your trial, it seems that you identified the "unity" with the "unity of $R$".

Comment: Then.... unity of the $I$ and unity of the $R$ is a different things, So My trial in (1) is incorrect.